# How to call a function from another function in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

`onFileSelected(event)` is called when file is selected from input type (from `Home.html`), everything works fine except when I try to call `this.callproducts(data,0,c_altcode)`.

Below is my `home.ts` code, where am I going wrong?

```
 onFileSelected(event)
  {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
        ...// some code here
    oReq.onload = function(e) {
        ...// some code here

if(oReq.status === 200)
          { 
            if(final_arr[0].hasOwnProperty("Altcode"))
            {
              var c_altcode =final_arr[0].hasOwnProperty("Altcode");

         // error coming in below line when i am trying to call this function which is outside `onFileSelected` function. 
          this.callproducts(data,0,c_altcode);           
                }

          }
        }

        oReq.send(null);
  }


callproducts(a,b,c,d){
...//some code here
}
```

Error coming when I am trying to call this function which is outside of `onFileSelected` function. The error is:

> [ts] Property 'callproducts' does not exist on type 'XMLHttpRequest'

Comment: try to set `oReq.onload = (e) => {}` instead of a `function`. function  creates its own scope where `this` points not to your component

Comment: You list home.ts, yet the error is expecting callProducts to live in XMLHttpRequest.
First off, stop using var. Use let or const. Secondly, perhaps try to gain a better understanding of scoping in JS.

Comment: try to write onFileSelected like this: onFileSelected = (event) => { .....} in addition to what @MaksymShevchenko said

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko  worked as you guided, i also want to kknow how can  i call a function in global scope, can you please guide me on this and thanks a lot for the help, i'll accept it as answer if you want

Comment: @user2828442 it depends on how your `home.ts` is organized. But for global functions it's preferably to use `export function fnName() { // code here... }`. But note that it won't be able to get the context of a class/component because it has it's own `this` pointing on itself. I recommend to read more about closures in javascript to understand why it happens. Hope you will find all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

"this" is equal to "oReq" if I am correct. I don't believe that "this." Is right. Try just callProducts without this.

Comment: it won't work, simply because callProducts is not declared in global scope, but inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `this.callproducts(data,0,c_altcode)` inside another function because it is not in your `component's` scope.

But you can try below.

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor() {}

 onFileSelected(event) {

    let file = event.target.files[0];

    oReq.onload = function(e) {

        if(oReq.status === 200) { 

            if(final_arr[0].hasOwnProperty("Altcode")) {

              let c_altcode =final_arr[0].hasOwnProperty("Altcode");
              HomePage.callproducts(data,0,c_altcode);           
            }
          }
        }
        oReq.send(null);
  }

static callproducts(a,b,c,d){

  }
}
```